# Enable mod_pagespeed for a Specific Directory Instead of Entire Virtual Host

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I read in the modpagespeed documentation that it's possible to enable mod_pagespeed in .htaccess file but is not recomended and the other section is Enabling the PageSpeed in the entire virtual host like this:

```
ModPagespeed On
ModPagespeedInheritVHostConfig on
ModPagespeedFileCachePath "/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/"
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css,combine_javascript
# Direct Apache to send all HTML output to the mod_pagespeed
# output handler.
AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER text/html

NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /www/example1
  ServerName www.example1.com
  ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain cdn.example1.com *example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

**My Question is:** Can I enable pagespeed in a specific directory inside the virtual host instead of the entire virtual host sites?

like this:

```
<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80>
    SuexecUserGroup "#1001" "#1001"

    ServerName DOMAIN.com
    ServerAlias www.DOMAIN.com
    ServerAlias mail.DOMAIN.com
    ServerAlias webmail.DOMAIN.com
    ServerAlias admin.DOMAIN.com

    DocumentRoot /home/DOMAIN/public_html

    <Directory /home/DOMAIN/public_html/demo-site/demo-2-site>
        AllowOverride Fileinfo Options

        #============= Something like that ==============
        ModPagespeed On
        ModPagespeedInheritVHostConfig on
        ModPagespeedFileCachePath "/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/"
        ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css,combine_javascript
        # Direct Apache to send all HTML output to the mod_pagespeed
        # output handler.
        AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER text/html

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```